# When to allocate a reference of a class to an instace of its parent class?

Tags: c++

I was reading a peace of code as below.

```
class CPolygon { 
    protected: 
        int width, height; 
    public: 
        void set_values (int a, int b) { width=a; height=b; } 
        virtual int area () { return (0); } 
}; 
class CRectangle: public CPolygon { 
    public: 
        int area () { return (width * height); } 
}; 
class CTriangle: public CPolygon { 
    public: 
        int area () { return (width * height / 2); } 
};
```

After while using this class we have a code that in this code a reference of **CRectangle** class is allocated to its parent "**CPolygon**" as below :

```
main () { 
   CRectangle rect; 
   CTriangle trgl; 
   CPolygon poly; 
   //*****This part is when a reference of the derived class is
   //allocated to an instance of its parent class *****

   CPolygon * ppoly = &rect; 
   .
   .
}
```

So my question is that when we do this and why this code line isn't like this :

```
CPolygon * ppoly = new rect;
```

Thanks

Comment: `&` before an *instance* of a class is an address operator. You're saying, "give me the address of this object". It is *not* a reference.

Comment: @HuuNguyen in C, a pointer was the only way to implement the concept of a reference. It doesn't surprise me that some people still use the same terminology, even if it's technically incorrect.

Comment: Ok. But why do we need the address of this class? Why didn't we instantiate like this? ---> CPolygon * ppoly = new rect;

Comment: `rect` is not a class, it is an instance. `CPolygon * ppoly = new rect;` will not compile. If you're asking why don't you create a `new` object, the answer depends on if you want one object or two. Every time you use `new` you're creating a new object.

Comment: Basically, if you want the base class pointer to point to an existing object, you use the address operator on an existing instance of the derived class. If you want the base class pointer to point to a new object, you create it with `new`. Both of these have their purposes, neither one is better than the other in the abstract, and which is appropriate at any given time depends on your use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code found in the example makes a pointer that points to a variable, `rect`, that already exists. Instead of pointing to the already extant variable, you could create a pointer to a new variable of that type like this

```
CPolygon* ppoly1 = new CRectangle;
```

However, `rect` is a variable, not a type, so calling `new rect` makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

`CPolygon * ppoly = new rect;` is an invalid construct, as `rect` is a variable defined in your `main()` method, while the `new` operator expects a class (or an array, or a struct, or etc.).

On the other hand, the `CPolygon * ppoly = &rect;` assignment sets the `ppoly` value to be the stack address of the `rect` variable. Casting pointers from child classes to parent classes is possible and is legit.

Also the title of your question is a little bit off the course, as you cannot allocate a reference, only pointers can be allocated (and not even those as actually the memory it's the one that's allocated/reserved and the address is returned)

Comment: I'd give the benefit of the doubt and assume a typo, it was actually meant to be `new Rectangle`.